# Radius of convergence of the solutions of the differential equation

Tags: sequences-and-series, ordinary-differential-equations, power-series

Justifies that the solutions are analytic functions in $t_0=0$ . Is it possible to determine the radius of cnvergencia series corresponding powers without calculate?

$$ (1-t^2)x''-2tx'+a(a+1)x=0$$ where $a\in\mathbb{R}$

Could some one help me or give me hint?

Answer (score 1):

If $a$ is an non-negative integer, the two solutions are exactly [Legendre Polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_polynomials), whose radius of convergence is $+\infty$. If $a$ is a real number, the power series solution (using [Frobenius Method](http://Frobenius%20method)) can be written in terms of the [hypergeometric function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function), 
$$
x(t) = {}_2F_1\left(-a,a+1;1;\frac{1-t}{2}\right).
$$
Since the hypergeometric function ${}_2F_1(a,b;c;z)$ has radius of convergence $1$, $x(t)$ is convergence on $|(t-1)/2|<1$, or the radius of convergence for the solution is $1$ (the power solution does not converge at $t=-1$).